# Returning an array

Tags: java

I am trying to make a method which allows the user to input an array along with a double in which the array is multiplied by, and then return the new array, however I am receiving an error with it.

Here is the code:

```
    public static void scaleA(double[] a, double s) {
    ArrayList<Double> newarray = new ArrayList<Double>();
    double newarray1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        newarray1 = s * a.get(i);
        newarray.add(newarray1);
    }
    return newarray;
}
```

However I am receiving the error:

`error: cannot find symbol (for a.size() and a.get(i))`

and

`error: cannot return a value from method whose result type is void (for return newarray;)`

Why am I shown these errors?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't return a value from a void method.  You want a return type of ArrayList<Double> in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is an array, *not* an `ArrayList`.  The analog operations you're looking for are `a.length` and `a[i]`.

It should also be noted that your method signature is `void`, hence your error "cannot return from a `void` type". You want to be returning `ArrayList<Double>`.

So, your signature would read like this:

```
public static ArrayList<Double> scaleA(double[] a, double s)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's intended to be a void method, you're not supposed to return anything. Void methods are more for doing things than they are for calculating things. In this case, you don't even have to create a new array, but only have to change the values inside the array (in fact, Java will get angry at you if you try to return something). You can still use return; but you write only the statement, as you're not supposed to or allowed to return anything.

It's also worth noting that in this case, `double[] a` is a *reference*, meaning it's only sending the location of that array as a parameter. This means that changes made to the array inside the method affect the values in the array outside the method (in contrast to s, which could be changed to something else (i.e. `s = 3;`), and the value sent down to the method wouldn't change outside of that method).

Here's an example of how you would change the values inside a:

```
public static void scaleA(double[] a, double s) {
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        a[i] *= s;
}
```

Alternatively, if you wished to leave the values in `a` intact and return an altered array, you could do this:

```
public static double[] scaleA(double[] a, double s) {
    double[] b = new double[a.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        b[i] = a[i]*s;
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over arrays use `array.length`. `size()` is a method of `List`.

Note that ArrayList and array are different things.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to these answers it you want to return your ArrayList you will want to change your return type from void to ArrayList